# How to protect react-native app from reverse engineering?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native

I have recently created an app with `react-native` and my concern is about react-native security.  I heard that react-native is not compiled and the code exists as it is in development.

So if we have some sensitive data in variables, what can we do for protecting that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to protect your `react-native` app in release, consider the following.

1. always save your sensitive data in `shared preferences` on
   **android** and `keychain` on **ios**, here is a nice package: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain
2. use `react-native proguard`
3. Encrypt your data and decrypt when you need it.
4. If possible save your data on server side

Comment: Read this article as it is your question answer, and I am sure you can get sense by reading that.
https://www.simform.com/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-your-android-app/